# Conditions for SetDirectory in Wix

Tags: wix, conditional-statements, computer-name

I've been trying to figure out why my condition isn't working for my SetDirectory. I haven't been able to find any examples of anyone actually doing this, only that it is possible to do so, according to the WiX documentation.

I've tried the following:

```
<SetDirectory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Value="TEST">ComputerName=LJPRESCOTT1</SetDirectory>
```

This compiles, but gets ignored at runtime. The files end up getting installed straight on the C:\ Drive, and not in C:\TEST like I'm aiming for.

---

and

```
<SetDirectory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Value="TEST">[ComputerName]=LJPRESCOTT1</SetDirectory>
```

This doesn't compile and throws a "Bad conditional string" error.

---

If I do this, it creates a directory named LJPRESCOTT1 as expected:

```
<SetDirectory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Value="[ComputerName]" />
```

So I know the Comp Name is correct.

Am I doing something wrong here, or is this not possible?

Thanks!

Comment: "isn't working" isn't a very useful description. Does it always fire? Never fire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the syntax `[ComputerName]` only when you are doing formatting, or using values that are of type `Formatted`, hence the syntax error in the second example.

But in the first example what you are doing is comparing the value of the `ComputerName` property with the value of the `LJPRESCOTT1` (public) property, which I imagine always evaluates to false. If you want to compare `ComputerName` to a hard string value you need some quotes:

```
ComputerName="LJPRESCOTT1"
```

Comment: Oh goodness... Sometimes the things I do (or in this case, DON'T do) astound me. Thanks so much.